# Кнопка "поделиться" в Telegram

Tags: telegram

Есть ли возможность добавить кнопку "Поделиться" на свой сайт через телеграм? Если есть, то где можно про это почитать?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/eduardobc/5770e1dadfd22f589951 попробуйте

Comment: Пример выше для whatsapp или я ошибась?

Comment: Там и телеграм есть. Вторая строка

Comment: А можно ли как-нибудь указать изображение статьи?